# Query caching not possible in superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am using superset in my organisation to query various data sources like athena, redshift etc. Now since it is used company wide a lot of queries are duplicate queries and produces the same result.

Is there a possibility of query caching in superset?

Answer (score 0):

You can use redis as superset cache.

See [Superset cache](https://blog.actorsfit.com/a?ID=01050-f2f24641-5638-4874-af9f-9af23cf7719d)

Answer (score -1):

Superset does have a caching mechanism.

See https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#caching

The original PR is here: https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#caching

Comment: This is not query caching

Comment: Do you happen to progress on this issue?